# Could not fetch model of type 'BuildEnvironment' using Gradle distribution

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm getting the below error when I have imported a gradle project and tried refreshing it. I'm new to gradle and using gradle wrapper. also, the gradle distribution exists in the repository.

Could not fetch model of type 'BuildEnvironment' using Gradle distribution 'http://repository.xyz.com:8080/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-4.8.1-all.zip'.
The specified Gradle distribution 'http://repository.xyz.com:8081/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-4.8.1-all.zip' does not exist.
http://repository.xyz.com:8080/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-4.8.1-all.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and set a proper `distributionUrl` there:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve the issue by following below steps :

1. Identify the Gradle wrapper version. Eclipse must use the same version while importing the project. By default, the Gradle wrapper version should be selected while importing the project. Otherwise, specify the version of the Gradle that your project is using.
2. Check if there is a syntax error in the build.gradle file
3. If still, you are getting the same issue after selecting the appropriate version, then delete the .gradle folder from the project and reimport the project.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem in Eclipse "forcing" eclipse to use the gradle wrapper.
So right click on the project in Eclipse, select properties, select gradle and select "override workspace settings" and be sure that "gradle wrapper is selected", see below:

[image: gradle wrapper settings in Eclipse]